# Is there a way for a Raspberry Pi to read data being sent from the Arduino with I2C?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am trying to read data from an Arduino to Raspberry Pi with the Python smbus module. This data that I am trying to get the Pi to read is just numbers, such as 200, 100 490, etc. basically similar to status codes to report its status to the Pi. However, I could not find the smbus documentation online and only found one piece of the puzzle, being that `bus.read_byte` **only** reads a byte from the received data from the Arduino.

Because of this, the current code can only display a 0 (or some mystery boxes) whenever run:

[The writing in blue is the data sent to the Arduino, and the boxes with the 0 are the received data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQFAq.png)

This the main code for full understanding of what's actually going on:

```
import time
from smbus import SMBus

clientAddr = 0x08
bus = SMBus(1)

def i2cWrite(msg): # Main Issue
  for c in msg:
    bus.write_byte(clientAddr, ord(c))
  return -1

def main():
  print("Send message to Arduino") 
  while True:
    print(bus.read_byte(clientAddr)) # Part that deals with printing messages from arduino on to python terminal
    msg = input("> ")
    print("...")
    i2cWrite(msg)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program Terminated Manually")
```

The information that I am trying to send from my Arduino is a output from a potentiometer, it runs normally and outputs its current value, just that it does not appear on the Pi side.

Arduino Code Main Parts:

```
// Function that executes whenever data is received from master
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
    // receive byte as a character, char converts unicode to character and add these characters into string
    received_str += (char)Wire.read();
  }
}

// Function that sends data to Master (Pi)
void sendData(int msg)
{
  Wire.write(msg);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  sendData(sensorValue);
  int n = received_str.toInt();
  //Serial.print(n);
  analogWrite(ENA, 255); //for H bridge PWM
  if (n > 0) {
    Serial.print(received_str);
    Serial.println();
    received_str = "";
  } else {
    received_str = "";
  }
}
```

Serial Monitor Output:
[Serial Monitor of Potentiometer actually working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixkzW.png)

So to my understanding, there is no issue with the Arduino side, but it just does not want to work as needed when trying to receive data from the Arduino to the Pi. Am I supposed to use something other than `read_byte`? If so, which?

**EDIT** What actually caused the boxes to appear was this section of the code:

```
def i2cRead():
    data = ""
    for i in range(0, 5):
            data += chr(bus.read_byte(clientAddr));
    print(data)
    time.sleep(0.5);
```

This was just added to see if it would fix the error, but unfortunately, it did not

Answer (score 0):

Figured this issue, turns out the Arduino code needed an `onRequest(event)` in the setup section to basically register a function to be called whenever the master would request data.

The master code on python was also worked on, successfully printing data from the arduino into the Pi

```
def i2cRead():
    data = bus.read_byte(clientAddr)
```